# How do I "normalize" two sample of values while keeping their ratio?

Tags: geometry, statistics

The values are floating point numbers and can be negative. What I would like to do is make them fit into an interval ( in my case it's [ 0 ; 400 ] ).

To give more details about my problem, I have two samples of x and y coordinates and I want to draw each point on a graph. I want to keep the ratio because it's supposed to represent a movement in function of time.

How do I proceed? Normalizing the normal way ( with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) method ) will make an object that stood still ( with a few noise ) look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIzmS.png) when I track its movement. Take a look at the bottom 3 graphs which represent a view from the side ( the camera is on the X axis ) from the front ( Y ) and from the top ( Z )

Thank you

Comment: Maybe multiply them by $400/\text{max}$, where max is the largest value ? Then, if all the values are positive, they remain positive, and the largest value becomes 400, and everything else is between 0 and 400.

Comment: what about negative values? should i add abs(min) to every value, then compute the max then multiply all by 400/max?